# Dropdown Buttons Open All at Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on an in-house application for a local company and I am trying to use jQuery for a simple button dropdown main page that just links to other places in the app, but when I click on one button they all open at the same time and I am not sure what I need to do to fix it.

I am fairly new to using jQuery but it fits my needs quite well for this web app and any help is appreciated.

It seems like it should be a simple fix I just can't seem to find it anywhere.

Also the dropdown on the top button opens below the second button which I am not sure why that happens.

```css
    .main-flex-container {
    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.main-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    width: 98vw;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Saira Condensed" , sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: #b31e1f;
    border: black;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.main-dropdown ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-90deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-dropdown ul.active {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg);

}

.main-dropdown ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.main-dropdown ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-dropdown ul li a:hover {
    background: #b33e3f;
}
#main-caret {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="main-flex-container">

    <div class="main-dropdown">


        <div class="main-dropdown-item">
            <button>TODAY <i class="fas fa-caret-down" id="main-caret"></i></button>
            <ul class="btn-dropdown">
                <li><a  href="#">Today</a>
                </li>
                <li><a
                       href="#">Map
                        Todays Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Timeclock</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="main-dropdown-item">
            <button>FIELD <i class="fas fa-caret-down" id="main-caret"></i></button>
            <ul class="btn-dropdown">
                <li><a
                       href="#">Timesheet
                        Lookup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hourly
                        Listing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Timeclock
                        Records</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('button').click(function () {
             $('ul').toggleClass('active')
         })
     })
    // $(".button").on('click', function (e) {
        // e.stopPropagation();
        // var $dropdown = $(this).siblings().fadeToggle();
        // $('.main-dropdown .btn-dropdown').not($dropdown).fadeOut();
    // });
   // $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        // $('.main-dropdown .btn-dropdown').fadeOut();
    // });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I noticed you're using single line comments ``//`` to comment out a block of javascript code. You can just do ``/* [all js code] */``.

Comment: thats just what my ide does when i use my comment shortcut lol

Comment: `$('ul')` selects all elements on the page. Giving your html structure, you have to limit the search to the `ul` `siblings` of the element receiving the click.

Comment: @Tuneer my editor will auto put those for me if I `ctrl + /`

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify in which `<ul>` you want to perform the action or it will perform the given action in all `<ul>`.
As cited above, siblings probably will do the job. You can try the following.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('button').click(function () {
         $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('active');
     })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out which button was clicked and then figure out the correct list to add the active class to based on which button was clicked. Right now it's adding active to all the `ul` elements on the page.

The example below should help you get on the right path.

```css
.main-flex-container {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Saira Condensed", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #b31e1f;
  border: black;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-dropdown ul.active {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.main-dropdown ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-dropdown ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #262626;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-dropdown ul li a:hover {
  background: #b33e3f;
}

#main-caret {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="main-flex-container">

    <div class="main-dropdown">


      <div class="main-dropdown-item">
        <button>TODAY <i class="fas fa-caret-down" id="main-caret"></i></button>
        <ul class="btn-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map Todays Jobs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Timeclock</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="main-dropdown-item">
        <button>FIELD <i class="fas fa-caret-down" id="main-caret"></i></button>
        <ul class="btn-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Timesheet Lookup</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hourly Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Timeclock Records</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('active')
      })
    })
    // $(".button").on('click', function (e) {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    // var $dropdown = $(this).siblings().fadeToggle();
    // $('.main-dropdown .btn-dropdown').not($dropdown).fadeOut();
    // });
    // $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // $('.main-dropdown .btn-dropdown').fadeOut();
    // });
  </script>
</body>
```